# Why does the negative multinomial distribution seem undefined at (0, ..., 0)?

Tags: distributions, multinomial-distribution, negative-binomial-distribution, discrete-data

It seems to me that the PDF of the negative multinomial distribution (as defined on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_multinomial_distribution), apologies could not find a good free reference) is not defined at (0, ..., 0).

Despite the tag, I am talking about negative **multi**nomial which is a multivariate extension of the negative binomial distribution.

For starters, the gamma function is not defined at 0. If I hand-wave this argument because $\frac{\Gamma(0)}{\Gamma(0)}=1$, I get a probability equal to 1 which makes obviously little sense, because other outcomes like (1, 0, ..., 0) or (1, 2, ...) could happen as well (assuming at least one probability of success is not zero). If p(0, ..., 0) =1 then p(any success)=0, which can't be true,  can it?

However, having 0 successes across all random variables is of course a valid outcome, so I am clearly mistaken.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A probability of $1$ makes perfect sense.

Comment: @whuber: 1 is an acceptable value for a probability, but it implies that the probability of any other event is 0... However with non zero probabilities of success, other events have a non zero  probability of occurring?

Comment: I added a sentence to clarify why I think a probability of 1 makes little sense in this case. I am not sure why you disagree, I must be misunderstanding something obvious.

Comment: If you look at the definition on wikipedia carefully, you will see that $k_0$ is defined as the count of the "failure" event, and it is included in the sum that is the argument of the gamma function.  Therefore, you can't have the sum equal to 0 unless you drew 0 samples.   In the regular negative binomial distribution, you also have the gamma function in the numerator including the "failure" event, as the argument is $r+x$ where $r$ is the number of failures that cause the sampling to stop (in one parameterization, at any rate.)

Comment: Oh, I see, I had fundamentally misunderstood the distribution. I was actually wondering why one the rv (X0) had a special status that was breaking the symmetry I expected. In fact X0 is "made up" with p0 defined in terms of the others p...

Comment: Follow up question: in this parameterisation they define p0=1-(p1+p2+...+Pm)... But each Pi is defined as the probability of success of the rv Xi, so why would the sum of the Pi be less than 1? Why is p0 well defined?

Comment: The failure event has to have a nonzero probability too (otherwise you sample forever!)  The $p_i, i > 0$ are unconditional probabilities of success, not probabilities of each category being a success conditional upon the observation being a success (in that formulation.)

Comment: What I meant was that you could easily have the sum of Pis >1 (imagine p1=.5, p2=.8, ...) leading to ill defined p0, unless their formula is wrong or,  more likely,  I am misunderstanding something again :)

Comment: I see what you did, but you're not quite getting the generating process right.  Let's assume the observation is a failure with probability $p_0$ and a success with probability $1-p_0$.  Then, if it's a success, which category does it belong to?  Those probabilities can be labeled $q_1, q_2, \dots, q_m$, and those probabilities will sum to 1.   The $p_i, i>0$ are just equal to $(1-p_0)q_i$.  So the generating process is: step 1, success or failure?  Step 2, if success, which category?  and the $p_i, i>0$ are the probabilities that the end result is a) success and b) for category $i$.

Comment: Ooooh,  I thought an observation was  a tuple (x0, ..., xm) where each xi was drawn from a NBD with probability of success Pi... And you are telling me the Xi are not rv but categories, and X is the rv valued in these outcomes, each outcome having probability Pi and the Pis thus summing to 1! It all makes sense now . I was coming at this with a misconception.  God I should delete this question,  I keep embarrassing myself :) Thanks a lot for taking the time, I really appreciate it!

Comment: No, don't delete it!  It's not at all uncommon to read the math and get it a little sideways, so to speak, and someday someone will also wonder why this distribution doesn't look like it should work, and maybe they will find this question.  I've failed to understand distributions at a first pass before too...